# Simple C++ program has no output

Tags: c++, g++, mingw

I encountered this issue while testing a program on my Windows computer, and simplified the code as much as I could to try to identify the problem.

I have `main.cxx`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "convert.h"

int main() {  
    std::cout << "hi" << std::endl;
}
```

`convert.h`:

```cpp
#include <string>

std::string convert (std::string);
```

and `convert.cxx`:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include "convert.h"

std::string convert (std::string str) {
     return str;
}
```

I compile with MinGW gcc version 9.2

```
> g++ main.cxx convert.cxx
```

but when running the output with

```
> ./a.exe
```

nothing happens.

For whatever reason, when I comment out the function definition in `convert.cxx`:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include "convert.h"

//string convert (string str) {
//     return str;
//}
```

Repeating the steps does give the expected output.

I also tried removing different include statements, `using namespace std` in different files, but the only thing that makes a difference is whether I define a function in `convert.cxx`.
What am I missing?

Comment: On Windows computer you should use MSVC compiler included in Visual Studio, MinGW is zero compared to native toolset.

Comment: @metablaster That's simply not correct.

Comment: There are issues with this code. Like the header not being guarded. Or the fact that you never actually call `convert()`. I also don't understand why you're using gcc 9.2. The current stable version is 12.2. If you did not install minGW via MSYS2, you likely did it wrong. I would toss it all out and install it via MSYS2. You'll also get the latest stable release.

Comment: Your "convert.h" header file is missing header guards.

Comment: When you say "nothing happens", do you mean a crash, a successful run (with result code code if you add `return 0;` to `main()`) or an blank line in the output?

Comment: @sweenish good points, I tried with header guards and calling convert() in main and the issue persists. I did end up installing MSYS2 and don't have the issue with that, but I am curious as to what the problem with my old installation could be.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, I would suggest that there is a header guard needed for your included file, which can be done by `#ifndef` / `#define` and at the end of the file you would use `#endif` to prevent multiple inclusions of said file.

Next, as the other comments mentioned, I would highly suggest you delete the current MinGW you are using, and get the most current version. It is much more stable and viable with VSC.